# image in tracking view 'failed to load' and is a negative keyframe

Tags: error

I tracked an object in a scene and set the background up. when I reloaded the file an hour later, the images were off. I retracked and same error an hour later. it worked at first.

I get an error in the VFX screen ( the footage tab ) says 'failed to load'. underneath that it says negative frame! so strange  my start frame is 1 end frame 53. but that one message says -53 / 53.

can any one help? I hate to have to redo the tracking for a second time!
[image]